# Need some guidance on executing Javascript with Jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, performance-testing, form-submit, jsr223

I've been learning Jmeter during the last couple of weeks so it's still a fresh subject for me. The last test I created consists of a login, some page navigation and a form submission in the end. The whole test works, but the content of the last form is not submitted to the database and I believe that happens because that's made through JavaScript, specifically this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['WebForm1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.WebForm1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

From what I've learned I should use JSR223 Sampler or Post-processor to execute scripts, but I don't know how to do it. Should I replicate the JavaScript code so it produces the same result <s>or can I simply reuse the original JavaScript</s>?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I guess I asked too early. I obviously can't reuse the JavaScript code. I guess it should be done with the methods from JMeterContext and JMeterVariables, which I just found out about. Am I going in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a tool like JMeter is to replicate user behaviour on a protocol level (in this case HTTP). JMeter will not build a DOM representation of your web site and therefore will not be able to execute the Javascript that you see executed in your browser. You should use an HTTP Request sampler, select POST HTTP method and put your form data into the parameters section. All that Javascript is pure client side behavior and therefore does not belong into your JMeter test.

Please provide some more detail, if you already tried that and it failed!

Comment: Hi! I'm already doing that and the request works with no problems. It simply has no effect on the database, that is, nothing's being actually added to it. 

Here's the POST Request: https://imgur.com/a/zFDenfY

Should I ignore this issue? Does this have any impact on the credibility and precision of my test?

Comment: What you can do is capture the XHR request by visiting the Network tab in the Chrome browser. This request should be put in the HTTP sampler as form encoded data (similar to what was recorded on the browser). Your test needs to have this as this data is being posted to the server.

Answer (score -1):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So you don't need to replicate the JavaScript, you need to replicate the [HTTP POST Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) which is produced by this JavaScript function using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

The most possible reason for your current request "not working" is missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of these `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` dynamic parameters.

If you just recorded these parameters and didn't do anything to them - you will not be able to successfully replay your script because these parameters have different values each time you access the application so they need to be **correlated**, example alrorithm:

1. Open first page of your application
2. Extract at least these `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` values using suitable JMeter Post-Processor (most likely [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor)) and store them into JMeter Variables
3. In subsequent request(s) replace recorded hard-coded values with the JMeter Variables from step 2

Check out [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter/) article for more comprehensive explanation with examples of working around the dynamic request parameters.

Also don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I rechecked and everything's well correlated. No problem with __EVENTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT in this test case. I tried  @sjmach suggestion involving XHR requests and it worked.